# Marginal Model Plots - R, car package

Tags: r, r-car

Is there a way to select which smooths to appear in the `car` package? Just the model smooth for example, or vice-versa?

```
require(car)
c1 <- lm(infant.mortality ~ gdp, UN)
mmps(c1)
```